# How to work with time in DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

Declared `DataFrame` like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ "ID"    : ["19", "11", "10", "55", "11", "11"],
                    'Date'  : rng)
```

and variables `TIME = pd.to_datetime("03.12.2020")`

And I need to have the same df as above but only with rows filtered by TIME variable, meaning with not a bigger date than 03.12.2020.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with convert `TIME` to correct datetimes by parameter `dayfirst` or `format`:

```
TIME = pd.to_datetime("03.12.2020", dayfirst=True)

df1 = df[df['Date'] <= TIME]
```

---

```
TIME = pd.to_datetime("03.12.2020", format='%d.%m.%Y')

df1 = df[df['Date'].le(TIME)]
```

Comment: Hey , jezreal can you look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574747/how-to-filter-a-list-based-on-ascending-values ?